# Rails - How to assign has_and_belongs_to_many between "Shops" and "Malls" (in controller and form views)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am making a simple rails app which acts as a directory of all Malls in Kuwait and Shops within each mall. I created a Shop model and Mall model and made the following associations:-

```
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :malls
end

class Mall < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :shops
end
```

and then I created a join table between shops and malls, containing shop_id and mall_id.

```
create_table "malls_shops", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "shop_id"
  t.integer "mall_id"
end
```

This is where I'm stuck:

1. What should I put in the controller exactly so that when I create (or update) a Shop, I can assign it to many different malls already existing in the Mall models database?
2. What should I put in the "new shop" form view to generate a field where the user can choose the malls the shop belongs to, and have the shop linked to those malls in the database when the shop is saved?

Answer (score 2):

You have two options to add some `shops` to a `mall`:

-This one will create the in middle relation for each added shop:

```
mall = Mall.first
mall.shops << Shop.find(1)
mall.shops << Shop.find(2)
```

-This one will set the ids which will control all the shops for you, will create the relation if not exist and will remove if id is not exit, this one is useful if you control the shops from a view so you will only send to you controller the ids and once you set `shop_ids` it will do everything for you (add and remove):

```
mall = Mall.first
mall.shops_ids = [2,3]
```

For what you can do in your view to control creating and updating from model [check this out](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-has-many-through)